# How to run a panel data in R

Tags: r, panel

I have created a matrix of 4600x5 dimensions, it is a panel data of the model that i want to emply, but I can not run the panel data model in R. Nether the plm package works nor the pdata.frame. Specifiacally, for the second it tells me ``package ‘pdata.frame’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)". What should I do?

```
library("plm")
data("mydata", package="plm")
Warning message: In data("mydata", package = "plm") : data set ‘mydata’ not found 
panel.model<-plm(inv~m1+m2, data = mydata, model="pooling") Error in if (!id.name %in% names(x)) stop(paste("variable ", id.name, : argument is of length zero
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow. Did you make sure you have all packages installed? You will need the package plm. Also it will be easier to help if you show what you have tried so far and provide some data (with dput)

Comment: I have installed the package plm, but is there some other package that I need to install also?

Comment: pdata.frame is not a package, rather a function inside the plm package. As already written, a good start is trying to replicate one example in the link below. If that works, you must be doing something wrong with your code.

Comment: I have made a panel data which i gave it the name mydata, this is a matrix of 4600x5 dimensions where the first and secont colums refer to the characteristic of the varaibles and the time and the 3rd, 4rth and 5th columns are the varaibles inv, m1 and m2 respectively...this is what I have as resutls
#library("plm")
Warning message:
In data("mydata", package = "plm") : data set ‘mydata’ not found
#data("mydata", package="plm")
#panel.model<-plm(inv~m1+m2, data = mydata, model="pooling")
Error in if (!id.name %in% names(x)) stop(paste("variable ", id.name,  : 
  argument is of length zero

Comment: Well I can not understand why it says data set 'mydata' not found since the matrix exists and it has the appropriate variables...what is going on?

Comment: ```data("mydata", package = "plm")``` makes no sense, as your data is not in the package plm. You can skip that. If you share your data people might be able to help you https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315885/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-r-data-on-stack-overflow, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What do you mean share my data? How can I do this...namely, how can I import such a matrix here? It is a mtrix of 4600x5 dimensions...If you can explain me how to do it, I will...but I can not see how this is done...

Comment: the 4600x5 matrix is too big to share here — take a smaller subset and use `dput()` which will give you something that you can paste into the question above.

Answer (score 0):

Here you find a good introduction to panel data econometrics with r, with several examples.
Make sure you can replicate some examples and then try with your data.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/vignettes/plmPackage.html